# CSS nightmode is not changing black text to white (filter invert)

Tags: css, darkmode, anki

I'm using CSS to change the appearance of night mode on Anki/Ankidroid. Since I use lot of highlight and the regular nightmode only change the backround and the text. It makes unreadable a white text with a yellow highlight... So I used the invert filter to invert all the colors and it worked terrific BUT the black text remains black and unreadable

My code is

```
.night_mode {
 background-color: #000000;
  filter: invert(1);
 
}

.night_mode img {
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

And here is a screenshot of the problem (even the red text changed to cyan and the yellow highlight to dark blue)[image]

Answer (score 0):

Anki already has a night mode feature, and I suggest you hook on that instead of making your own classes. You can read more [here](https://docs.ankimobile.net/night-mode.html), but the main point is that when you go in the settings and set night mode, the tag that contains all the content of the card has the class `nightMode`.